# Display a certain number Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to get a ListView to display a certain number of items at one time. Here is what I have now. The items and relatives are just buttons and each have a ListView underneath them.

[image]

I would like for it to look like the following with two items:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ulHoUHe.png]

This is what my layout looks like. Any helps is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_login">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Log out"
            android:id="@+id/backToLoginButton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:onClick="onLogoutClick"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:id="@+id/logoView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/misc_no_image"
            android:id="@+id/profilePhotoView"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/backToLoginButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Full Name"
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profilePhotoView"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/photoUploadButton"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_camera"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_above="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/nameTextView"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textLayout">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:id="@+id/relativesRegisterButton"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_detail_header"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:onClick="onAddRelativesClick"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:text="Relatives"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:id="@+id/vehicleRegisterButton"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeListView"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_detail_header"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:onClick="onAddVehicleClick"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeListView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:text="Vehicles"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:id="@+id/vehicleTextView" />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeListView"
                    android:background="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativesRegisterButton"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/vehicleListView"
                    android:background="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/vehicleRegisterButton"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code when populating the listview:

private void setVehiclesList(){
        String[] userNames = new String[vehicleJSONDataArray.length()];

```
    for(int i = 0; i < vehicleJSONDataArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject relative = vehicleJSONDataArray.optJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject relativeUser;
        try {
            relativeUser = relative.getJSONObject("vehicle");
            userNames[i] = relativeUser.getString("brand") + " " + relativeUser.getString("model");
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }

    ListAdapter vehicleListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userNames);
    ListView vehicleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vehicleListView);
    vehicleListView.setAdapter(vehicleListAdapter);
```

Comment: how are you currently adding the items to the list view?

Comment: @Alex Lord Mordor :I'm using a listview.

Comment: @Rich Luick: The items are populated from json containing the items and vehicles.

Comment: Are you only getting the one "bread" result from the json? Maybe if you posted your code for that it could be helpful

Comment: No there are more items in there but only one is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a very serious mistake : you are trying to add a ListView inside a scrollView. ListView scrolls automatically and it is a really bad idea to put a scroll inside another scroll.

All you need is an [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Comment: If I remove the Scroll view and have too many items I can no longer even see the vehicles. I like the scroll functionality and would just like to display more than one item, specifically two, at a time while keeping the scroll functionality.

Comment: It is oneway for you to use ExplanableListView. The scroll functionality that you need remains by default  in ExplandableListView. Please take a look at this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ cause I think that you are missing  the basic capabilities of Listviews

Comment: I don't want the ExpandableListView functionality. I want to displays two items at a time from my ListView and be able to scroll through the list. I don't want a button to expand and show the full list.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use an expandable list view as suggested previously but if you want to format it the way you currently have it, all you have to do is use a simple array adapter.

```
//create a string array with the list entries
String[] items = new String[2];
items[0] = "Bread";
items[1] = "Milk";

//array adapter using the array above
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

//attach it to whatever listview here 
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Comment: I update the question to include how I populated the ListView and it was similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the height value as a static, not `wrap_content`, maybe some dp in the scrollview to make more items visible.

Comment: I tried adding a static value like the following but the ListView didn't show when I did: 
<ListView
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

Comment: you should put a higher value, something like 25dp or more. 0dp will show NOTHING because it is a None-like value and if you dont put a valid unit (like `dp`) it's the same thing, nothing shown